# How do I make this Macro repeat in vba

Tags: vba, excel

The following macro is designed to take an input string from the user and search through a directory (constant) for that input string. It then copies the corresponding information in the same row of the input string and the headers as well. After it is done copying and pasting that info, the macro ends. I would like to make it so that, after the macro is done copying and pasting info it asks for another string and does the search again, but copies the info on the next line.
Please let me know if I can provide any more information, I've been working on this for 2 weeks now and can't figure it out. The code is below.

```
'Author: Michael Majdalani
Public WS As Worksheet
Sub SearchWKBooksSubFolders(Optional Folderpath As Variant, Optional Str As Variant)

Dim myfolder As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Single
Dim Folders() As String
Dim Folder As Variant
Dim p As Integer
ReDim Folders(0)



'This is where the folder path is chosen, for the current application
'It is constant, If you would like to choose a different folderpath
'Uncomment the commented lines and comment the declaration of myfolder

If IsMissing(Folderpath) Then
    Set WS = Sheet1
    'With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        '.Show
        myfolder = "O:QUALITY\INSPECTION REPORTS\"
    'End With

'This is where the user is prompted to enter the string, if no string is entered
'A message will appear. If a string is entered, It will enter the headers
'"Search String" and "links" and the correlated information
'Value here keeps track of the directory and which subfolders/folders
'it is searching through

    Str = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Search string:", Title:="Search all workbooks in a folder", Type:=2)
    If Str = "" Then MsgBox "No string entered, Please try again"
    WS.Range("A1") = "Search string:"
    WS.Range("A2") = Str
    WS.Range("B1") = "Links"
    Folderpath = myfolder
    Value = Dir(myfolder, &H1F)
Else
    If Right(Folderpath, 2) = "\\" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Value = Dir(Folderpath, &H1F)
End If

'The first part of this do Until loop has a lot to do with how the maneuvering is completed
'within the folder path and directory for excel to search through every folder/subfolder
'needed.

Do Until Value = ""
    If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
    Else
        If GetAttr(Folderpath & Value) = 16 Then
            Folders(UBound(Folders)) = Value
            ReDim Preserve Folders(UBound(Folders) + 1)
        ElseIf (Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm") And Left(Value, 1) <> "~" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim wb As Workbook
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Folderpath & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz")
            On Error GoTo 0
            'If there is an error on Workbooks.Open, then wb Is Nothing:
            If wb Is Nothing Then
                Lrow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                WS.Range("A" & Lrow).Value = Value
                WS.Range("B" & Lrow).Value = "Password protected"
            Else
                'For each sheet in the workbooks, the next loop will search through the first
                'column of every sheet in every workbook found in the directory chosen.
                'It then creates the link, as well as updating value to end the loop.

                For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
                    'Expand all groups in sheet and Unprotect
                    sht.Unprotect

                    sht.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8, ColumnLevels:=8

                    'c here is used to search for the user input string
                    Set c = sht.Columns(1).Find(Str, After:=sht.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        firstAddress = c.Address
                        Do
                            Lrow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                            WS.Range("B" & Lrow).Value = Value
                            WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("B" & Lrow), Address:=Folderpath & Value, SubAddress:= _
                            "'" & sht.Name & "'" & "!" & c.Address, TextToDisplay:="Link"
                            Set c = sht.Cells.FindNext(After:=c)
                            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

                        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                    End If

                    'if c is nothing, continue
                    If c Is Nothing Then GoTo Cont Else


                    'if c is equal to our searched string then it will loop through the
                    'adjacent thirty cells copying and pasting all the information
                    'to the main workbook
                    If Str = c.Formula Then
                       Dim i As Integer

                       For i = 1 To 30

                    If IsEmpty(wb.Sheets(sht.Name).Range(firstAddress).Offset(0, i)) Then GoTo Done

                        Dim cnt As Long


                        'cnt is the amount of cells between the searched string and the top
                        'of that workbook, used to copy the headers to the main workbook
                        cnt = ((Range(firstAddress, "A1").Cells.Count) - 1) * -1


                        'Copy and paste info
                        wb.Sheets(sht.Name).Range(firstAddress).Offset(0, i).Select
                        Selection.Copy

                        WS.Range("B2").Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial

                        'Copy and paste header info
                        wb.Sheets(sht.Name).Range(firstAddress).Offset(cnt, i).Select
                        Selection.Copy

                        WS.Range("B1").Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial

                        Next i





                    'When done, close the workbook and autofit the cells on the main
                    'workbook
Done:                   wb.Close False
                        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                        End
                    End If
              'Continues the loop if the string is not found
Cont:             Next sht
                wb.Close False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    'Increments value to the next directory
    Value = Dir
Loop

'Recursive loop
For Each Folder In Folders
    Call SearchWKBooksSubFolders(Folderpath & Folder & "\", Str)
Next Folder

Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Just end with a prompt, if "yes", ask for the next input for this sub and call the sub itself. If no, let it go to end sub.

Comment: Okay, This worked in repeating the process. But there's two problems, the first is that it is overwriting the data from the previous search. I'd like it to increment a row and then past the information right after the first. The second is for some reason the excel sheet is just not responding to my click, it is running with no macros it's not frozen.

Comment: That's 2 new issues: 
For overwriting your old values: You can use an incrementer that is outside of the scope of the sub itself (don't use `dim something` within the sub, but use `public something` before the `sub test(params here)` line. 
The "Excel sheet is not responding to my click" - makes sense, as long as stuff is running it won't. You'd have to clarify your question and describe the **exact** desired behavior if you want more explicit info.

Comment: So I would declare the integer outside of the sub, set it to 0 and then increment it inside the sub?

Comment: Well I can't set it to 0 outside of the sub, and if I do it inside the sub then everytime I recursively call it, it will just reset to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply some recursion as follows:

This sub will msgbox the inputstring, ask if you want to do it again, gets a new input string and calls itself. This way it will just keep going with different strings (in your case `folderpath`) until the user exits.

**Edit:** Added an incrementer that allows for the recursion to take the next row each time.

```
Public SomeIncrementer as Integer

Sub DoStuff(str As String)
Dim repeat As Integer
Dim nextstring As String
    Worksheets(1).Range("A" & SomeIncremeter).value = str
    repeat = MsgBox("Again?", vbYesNo)
    If repeat = vbYes Then
        SomeIncrementer = SomeIncrementer + 1
        nextstring = InputBox("Next string?")
        DoStuff (nextstring)
    End If
End Sub

'And start from here:
Sub Test()
    SomeIncrementer = 1
    DoStuff "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still running into the problem where the previous data is being overwritten. I'm trying to preserve a constant "p" so that i can offset this "WS.Range("A2") = Str" to be "WS.Range("A2").Offset(p,0) = Str" but I can't figure out how to make p increment/save through the function call

Comment: See edit - I added an incrementer to take the next line each time the function calls itself. You can do the same kind of thing for "p", just don't declare it as a constant. The other option is to do a multiplication of "p" to get your starting cells for each iteration, but that'll only work when you know exactly how many rows you'll copy. Finally, you could also set this starting row with `.end(xlDown).Row + 1` or something like that.